# Android Recyclerview not appearing until EditText box touched

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Okay. So I'm having a problem that's very similar to the one in this thread (though that solution didn't work for me): [RecyclerView not populated until SearchView interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236417/recyclerview-not-populated-until-searchview-interaction)

I have a recyclerview that's populated by Objects coming from a Firebase listener. The objects are coming in just fine (I see them in the log) but my recyclerview doesn't appear until I touch the "EditText" field.  I don't actually even have to send or even type anything... I just touch the box and then the recyclerview appears... but not before.

I've tried a few different things (including the accepted answer on that question and a few others here). And I've tried setting the focus to that box from the very beginning... but nothing seems to help.

Here's the code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        style="@style/FullWidthEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:text="to:"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tofield"
        style="@style/FullWidthEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="Juan Foo"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/writebox"
        style="@style/FullWidthEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:hint="Message"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_send"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/responses"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/linearlayout_sent"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the code for the Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write);
        session = new SaveSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
        toField = findViewById(R.id.tofield);
        String to = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");

        if (to == null) {
            loadReceive();
            toField.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("username"));

            msgEdit = findViewById(R.id.writebox);
            //msgEdit.requestFocus();
            msend_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            msend_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    submitForm();
                }
            });

            mMessageRecycler = findViewById(R.id.responses);
            final MessageListAdapter adapter = new MessageListAdapter(MessageActivity.this, messageList);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //  Collections.reverse(events);
                    mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, messageList);
            mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
           // mMessageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messageList.size());


        //    loadReceive();


        }else{
            toField.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));

            msgEdit = findViewById(R.id.writebox);
            msend_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            msend_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    submitForm();
                }
            });

            SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String uid = preferences.getString("nUID",null);
            final String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
            final String titre = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
            final String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("body");
            final String nom = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

            long num = Long.valueOf("4543453");


            mMessageRecycler = findViewById(R.id.responses);
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, messageList);
            mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


            messageList.add(new Message("its", "basic", "lee", text, nom, num));

          //  mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");



            //SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
//            editor.putString(nom, text); // changed from "liked"
//            // remove this line editor.putString("pic_id", foto_id);
//            editor.commit();

            final MessageListAdapter adapter = new MessageListAdapter(MessageActivity.this, messageList);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //  Collections.reverse(events);
                    mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }

           // loadReceive();

    }

    private void loadReceive() {

        mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

        Query queryRecycler = mDatabase2.limitToLast(5);
        queryRecycler.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {

                Message newMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                messageList.add(newMessage);
                //moonList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Memf.class));
                mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("Msg added ", newMessage.body);



            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
                moonList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Memf.class));
//                    messageList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class));
//                    mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                    messageList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class));
//                    mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
//                    messageList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class));
//                    mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Since I'm not even pressing the "send" button... I really don't understand why pressing the "EditText" box should do anything at all.  But the second I touch it the recyclerview completely populates. I'd really like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no need to 'adapter', you can just use 'mMessageAdapter' adapter,

second, put below lines

```
mMessageAdapter = new DealAdapter();
mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

before

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  Collections.reverse(events);
        mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
    }
});
```

In brief, please replace onCreate() with below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write);
    session = new SaveSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
    toField = findViewById(R.id.tofield);
    String to = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");

    if (to == null) {
        loadReceive();
        toField.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("username"));

        msgEdit = findViewById(R.id.writebox);
        //msgEdit.requestFocus();
        msend_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        msend_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });

        mMessageRecycler = findViewById(R.id.responses);
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, messageList);
        mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  Collections.reverse(events);
                mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
            }
        });
       // mMessageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messageList.size());


    //    loadReceive();


    }else{
        toField.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));

        msgEdit = findViewById(R.id.writebox);
        msend_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        msend_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String uid = preferences.getString("nUID",null);
        final String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
        final String titre = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        final String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("body");
        final String nom = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

        long num = Long.valueOf("4543453");


        mMessageRecycler = findViewById(R.id.responses);
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(this, messageList);
        mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        messageList.add(new Message("its", "basic", "lee", text, nom, num));

      //  mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");



        //SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
//            editor.putString(nom, text); // changed from "liked"
//            // remove this line editor.putString("pic_id", foto_id);
//            editor.commit();

        final MessageListAdapter adapter = new MessageListAdapter(MessageActivity.this, messageList);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  Collections.reverse(events);
                mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

       // loadReceive();

}

}
```

Comment: Okay. I've rephrased the question. My Recyclerview IS populated... it just doesn't APPEAR until I tap the "EditText" box.  As I explained in the description... the adapter is populated just fine... the recycler view simply doesn't appear until I tap the EditText box. (And ONLY when I tap the EditText box.) Not anywhere else on the screen.

Comment: I mean I tried what you suggested... it didn't work. Same result.

Comment: . this is should be in .setAdapter() as the RecyclerView is not attached to the adapter unless you tap the EditText .  let me check again

Comment: if that won't work, please let me know what is the response whenever remove the EditText & using the same code?

Comment: Winner... winner...! Setadapter should be "mMessageAdapter" not "messageList"... but once I changed that... it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I will help you! you need to write a function in your MessageListAdapter adapter

```
 void setData(Message list){

   if(youradapterlist != null){
   youradapterlist.add(list);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
    }}
```

and call this function in

```
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {

        Message newMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
           if(mMessageAdapter != null){
         mMessageAdapter.setData(newMessage );
         }
        }
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: It did not. That only doubles the messages. I have something similar in the activity already for notifying data set change. It's just that... for whatever reason... it won't show up until I touch the edittbox. Hell of a mystery...

Comment: Okay. I've rephrased the question. My Recyclerview IS populated... it just doesn't APPEAR until I tap the "EditText" box.  As I explained in the description... the adapter is populated just fine... the recycler view simply doesn't appear until I tap the EditText box. (And ONLY when I tap the EditText box.) Not anywhere else on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may adding data whiout using

> notifyDataSetChanged();

i spend 2 hours on that !.

Comment: But I *am* using it: " mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: Be sure that u notify adapter after you set new data